# symfony1, hosting, document root and apache mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, symfony1, hosting

I've read a lot about this but i can't make it work, so, i'm posting a question

I have a `Symfony1` project with 2 app(front, admin), the hosting document root is `public_html`, so the folder structure look like:

```
/public_html
|--/apps/
|--/cache/
|........
|--/web/
```

the support team told me they can't not change the document root for me, so, all i have to do is start trying with `.htaccess` and this is what i did:

```
RewriteEngine on
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php
RewriteBase /web/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/admin.php/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/$1 [QSA,L]
```

this works ok, but symfony generate the urls with `/web`, so, i created a custom class that extend from `sfPatternRouting`, override the `generate` function to return something like this:

```
public function generate($name, $params = array(), $absolute = false) {
    $url = parent::generate($name, $params, $absolute);
    $pattern = '/\/web\//';
    return preg_replace($pattern,'/', $url);
}
```

and this works ok again, i have pretty url and works ok, but, when y try to access to `http://my.domain.com/admin.php/` i get `404 Page not found error` and all for the admin app isn't working, url `/admin.php/services` same result, always the same, so, i recreate the same environment in my local pc, and works ok, but in the hosting it doesn't work.

So, the .htaccess config i made should work? do i need more conditions and rewrites rules for this to work the way i want?
can the .htaccess that comes inside the `/web` folder affect?

the hosting is www.bluehost.com
Need some help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to redirect all requests to the /web folder.

```
RewriteEngine on
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web(/|$)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/$1 [QSA]
```

Your hosting provider might require this line.  Note that I removed [L] from the previous `RewriteRule`, which allows the next rule to work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+\.php[45]?)/ $1 [QSA]
```

If this ends up sending you to the wrong page, you will need to determine what querystring the page takes for traditional (non-mod_rewrite) navigation, and insert that.  Assuming that it is `page`:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+\.php[45]?)(/.*)$ $1?page=$2 [QSA]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but, same result, it works ok for the front app, a think because its frontend controller is `index.php`, but the admin app which fontend controller is `admin.php`, doesn't work at all without the `/web/` on the url. but this only happens in the hosting, because locally in my pc with the rules you gave me, works ok. Any clue?